# Calling getResources() ten times Android

Tags: android, string, getresource

so as my question says, I am in a situation where I need to get ten different strings using getResources() and then compare them to a string the user enters.
This is how I'm doing it currently:

```
if(string == getResources().getString(R.string.x))
```

Since this code is going to be repeated ten times for ten different strings in R.java, I'm wondering if there is going to be a loss in performance by calling getResources() so many times.

Is there an easier solution, like creating an object from getResources() and then getting one string at a time from that object?

Sorry if I'm blabbering, I'm new to this.

Thanks!

Comment: `string ==` ... good luck ... anyway http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: if you are so worried just assign it once: `final Resources resources = getResources()` . Also for string you have to use `equals` not `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you can do something like this:

```
Resources res = yourContext.getResources();
//use this res variable instead of getResources() function a small example
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.id.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats the answer I wanted.. sort of. Just a thought, supposing I'm in the onCreate() method, can I just type in "this" in place of yourContext, or do I need to specify it like, "MainActivity.this"?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to add the strings you're getting as a `string-array`

```
<string-array name="string_array_name">
    <item>text_string</item>
    <item>text_string</item>
</string-array>
```

and get your array:

```
String[] myArr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.string_array_name);
```

and loop over them .. you'll call `getResources()` once ...

But anyways resources object is a shared object throughout the application and you're merely calling it's getter so no performance isuue there

Answer (score 0):

you can **create** an **array** in `string.xml`

string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="item_array">
        <item>item 1</item>
        <item>item 2</item>
        <item>item 3</item>
        <item>item 4</item>
...
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

in your java code you access this as

```
String[] mTestArray =   getResources().getStringArray(R.array. item_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the `getResources()` repeated call, create before a **variable of type Resources**, and use it instead of the call, as follows:

```
Resources res = getResources();
if (string == res.getString(R.string.x);
```

In this way, you can also pass the variable as a parameter to other methods/functions, having only one call to `getResources()` in all your code.